# Atheros AR9462 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, configuration, atheros

can anyone help me out installing a atheros AR9462 on Ubuntu 16.04?

I've tried configuring /etc/network/interfaces, but that didn't seem to fix it.

**UPDATED BELOW:**
My /etc/network/interfaces config looks like:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wireless-essid <my-wireless-sid-here>
        wireless-mode Managed
        wireless-key <my-wireless-psk-here>
```

(restart)

I have also tried:

```
auto wlp5s0
iface wlp5s0 inet dhcp
        wireless-essid <my-wireless-sid-here>
        wireless-mode Managed
        wireless-key <my-wireless-psk-here>
```

Whenever I tried to either configure and then do a `sudo reboot` to restart the machine....the Bluetooth always works, the wifi doesn't.

I test that my computer is recognizing the chip with: `lspci | grep -i wlan0` - it comes up with:

```
wlan0 was renamed to wlp5s0
```

If I try to pull up the wifi icon (in upper right corner of screen) - it never shows any available networks.

What may be the problem here? Thanks

Comment: Additional drivers aren't needed for Atheros usually. There's no need for user intervention. You may have a problem with firmware but that should be all. Please add more information. What isn't working?

Comment: @CelticWarrior - it appears my wlan0 was renamed to wlp5s0 ?

Comment: Yes, that's normal, started with 16.04 and has no impact whatsoever. Please edit your question and describe exactly what the is. Thanks.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - Thanks for letting me know. I updated my question with more details - thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this would work for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/898824/wifi-and-bluetooth-coexistence-qualcomm-atheros-ar9462-ubuntu-16-04 I was solving a different issue and this seems to have fixed it for the same wireless card.