# WiFi and Bluetooth coexistence: Qualcomm Atheros ar9462: Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, bluetooth

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on Fujitsu UH552. Every thing has been working fine until I connected Bluetooth wireless headphone. My machine has qualcomm atheros ar9462 (wifi + bluetooth) module.

Problem:
If I use both Bluetooth headphone and WiFi at the same time they interfere, WiFi slows down and audio on headphone has glitches. Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Note:Upon googling I found this solution

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

but this is not working for me.

Comment: That command is for Intel adapters only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since yours is an Atheros wireless device and not an Intel, it is not surprising that a driver parameter for an Intel is not working. Let's try a better option:

```
sudo -i
rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: Works well for me so far. Reboot wasn't necessary, I did `modprobe -r ath9k; sleep 5; modproble ath9k` But it's a fair suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is for the `ath9k` driver only. There's no `btcoex_enable` option for the `ath10k` driver, at least at the moment.

Comment: @YuryKirienko Almost every wireless driver solution is only valid for the specific driver mentioned. You can find the available parameters for your device with: `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep parm` If you need additional help, please ask your own new question.