# Ubuntu 18.04 - Poor Wi-FI when connected with Bluetooth Headphone

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, headphones

Whenever i connect my Bluetooth headphone in Ubuntu my Wi-fi starts to drop and slow down. But just by turning the bluetooth off the wi-fi connection gets normal again. How can I use the two normally? (Obs: I've came from Windows and it was working fine)

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02`enter code here`:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:116a Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I have the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060094/bluetooth-audio-interfering-with-wifi it seems there is no solution

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with QCA9377 `0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc.` bluetooth adapter. I answered in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1137557/949012), I solved by including `0cf3:e500` to blacklist in `btusb.c` and recompiling the modules. You can check the link if you want to see how I arrived to this answer.

Unfortunately this fix is still not applied in official repository. But you can do that following the steps below:

**1) Download Kernel Source** (consider changing '4.18.0' for whichever version you're using):

```
# In a working directory, run:
apt source linux-source-4.18.0
```

**2) Fix code for this device.** Include 0x0cf3:e500 to blacklist in `btusb.c`.

```
# Here the source was extracted to linux-hwe-4.18.0.
cd linux-hwe-4.18.0/drivers/bluetooth

# Change btusb.c with editor of your choice. Ex:
vim btusb.c
```

In `btusb.c` file just add `{ USB_DEVICE(0x0cf3, 0xe500), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },` to `static const struct usb_device_id blacklist_table[]`.

File should be something like this:

```
static const struct usb_device_id blacklist_table[] = {
    ...
    /* QCA ROME chipset */
    ...
    { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3015), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
    { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3016), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
    { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x301a), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
    { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3496), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
    // This is the fix for QCA9377 bluetooth 0x0cf3:e500
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0cf3, 0xe500), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
    ...
```

**3) Compile modules.** You may need some need `make` and `build-essential` for that, install using 'sudo apt install make build-essential' if they are not installed.

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
```

**4) "Install" and reboot.** Replace btusb module for the new btusb and reboot.

```
# You may do a backup of the old file:
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.backup

# Copy and replace btusb.ko to module location:
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/

# Reboot and test
reboot
```

I didn't experience any problem after that. Wireless seems ok, bluetooth headset also seems to be ok.

**If you also could test**, please, share results here. If it really solves the problem we can ask this to be included in future linux kernel versions.

Comment: I just got a QCA9377 device… and I'm surprised to find that this problem _still_ isn't fixed [in the official `btusb.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c) as of 2021. Has anyone tried to submit it to the kernel devs?

Comment: I've submitted a patch to the Linux-Bluetooth kernel maintainers to add QCA_ROME support for this device: https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=162136440231258&w=2

Comment: Thank you @Dan for submitting this patch! I really appreciate it. Following your patch on linux repository, it were merged days ago, sadly it is not in 5.13 :( but hope it will be in 5.14.