# Wireless speed drops when audio is played over bluetooth

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

When trying to play any type of audio over my [Bluetooth Earphones](https://www.amazon.in/Airdopes-441-Technology-Immersive-Resistance/dp/B084DS51NC) Wifi speeds drop below 100Kbps. When I stop the audio the speed is back to normal at 25Mbps. I tested it in on other machines and did not face this issue.

I have tried disabling coexistence in iwlwifi as per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060094/bluetooth-audio-interfering-with-wifi). I have read about bluetooth and wifi using the same band (2.4Ghz), however this problem occurs only on my laptop. I also updated linux kernel from 4.16 to 5.4. Also, I thought it might be a driver issue but I can't seem to find correct drivers.

Operating system -

`Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel - 5.4.0-52-generic`

These are the drivers and configuration -

```
$ `hciconfig -a` 

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 2C:33:7A:00:D1:E4  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:269077 acl:136 sco:0 events:37073 errors:0
    TX bytes:21963711 acl:35474 sco:0 commands:1534 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'A12'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xe2f
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x9f73
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

Output from -

`lshw -class network`

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 2c:33:7a:00:d1:e3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.199 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```